# BBC Code Dice Roller in PHP

Tags: php

I do not program PHP too often. I wanted to write a dice-roller bbc code parser for my forums. What do you see that can be improved?

You can see the code running live here: https://joshuad.net/misc/dice-test.php

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
<h2>Syntax</h2>
<ul>
<li><strong>Basic Rolls:</strong> NdM: Roll N dice with M sides. i.e. 3d20 rolls three twenty sided dice.</li>
<li><strong>Add Modifiers:</strong> 1d20+1 or 1d20-5: Add (or subtract) the indicated amount from the roll</li>
<li><strong>Reroll Low Results:</strong> 1d20r3: Roll 1d20, but keep re-rolling if the result is 3 or lower.</li>
<li><strong>Keep Highest Rolls</strong>: 4d6^3: Roll 4d6, but keep only the 3 highest results, discarding the remainder.</li>
<li><strong>Keep Lowest Rolls</strong>: 4d6v3: Roll 4d6, but keep only the 3 lowest results, discarding the remainder.</li>
<li><strong>Note:</strong> You cannot have ^ and v in the same roll -- 3d6^1v1 is invalid.</li>
<li><strong>Compound Rolls are OK:</strong> 3d6-2d6-5+3: Roll 3d6, subtract 2d6, subtract 5, add 3</li>
<li><strong>Whitespace is ignored:</strong>  1 d 6 and 1d6 are the same thing. '1 d 2 0' will work too, all white space
is completely ignored</li>
<li><strong>Syntax Errors</strong> Any syntax errors cause the entire roll to be considered invalid.</li>
</ul>
<h2>Tests</h2>
<?php 
   $rolls = array("1 d2 0", "-1d20+5", "d20", "2d20^1", "4d6r1^3", "5d20^3", "5d8v2", "2d20v1", "5+3d4", "3d20^1",
   "3d6r1 + 1d4r2", "-1d20", "1d20+5", "1d20 + 5", "1d-20", "1d20+1d6", "5d20-3d6", "1d6r2", "5d6r-6", "3d20^1v1",
   "1d20r30", "1d20r20", "1d20r19", "1d20v2", "1d20v1", "1d20^2");
   foreach ($rolls as $roll) {
      $rollResult = do_jroll($roll);
      echo $rollResult['detailText'] . "<br><br>";
   }
?>
</body>
</html>

<?php
function do_jroll($inputText) {
   $INVALID_ROLL_ERROR = "Invalid Roll Code";
   $inputClean = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $inputText);
   $inputClean = strtolower($inputClean);
   $detailText = "";
   $rrx = '\d+d\d+(r\d+|\^\d+|v\d+)*'; //rrx short for "roll regex" - matches a single roll token
   if (preg_match("/^[+-]?($rrx|\d+)([+-]($rrx|\d+))*$/", $inputClean) && preg_match_all("/[\^v]/", $inputClean) <= 1) {
      $rollTokens = preg_split('/(?=[+-])/', $inputClean, null);
      $rollTotal = 0;
      foreach ($rollTokens as $rollToken) {
         if (empty($rollToken)) {
           continue;
         }
         $rollSign = 1;
         if ($rollToken[0] === "-") {
            $rollToken = substr($rollToken, 1);
            $rollSign = -1;
         } else if ($rollToken[0] === "+") {
            $rollToken = substr($rollToken, 1);
         }
         if (preg_match('/^\d+$/', $rollToken)) {
            $rollTotal += $rollToken * $rollSign;
         } else {
            preg_match('/(\d+)d(\d+)/', $rollToken, $capture);
            $numberOfDice = $capture[1];
            $diceType = $capture[2];
            preg_match('/r(\d+)/', $rollToken, $capture);
            $rerollThreshold = (sizeof($capture) >= 2 && $capture[1]) ? $capture[1] : 0;
            preg_match('/v(\d+)/', $rollToken, $capture);
            $keepLowCount = (sizeof($capture) >= 2 && $capture[1]) ? $capture[1] : 0;
            preg_match('/\^(\d+)/', $rollToken, $capture);
            $keepHighCount = (sizeof($capture) >= 2 && $capture[1]) ? $capture[1] : 0;
            $detailText .= (empty($detailText) ? "" : "<br>") . "<strong>" . ($rollSign == -1 ? "-" : "") . "$rollToken Results:</strong> ";
            $subTotal = 0;
            $rollResults = array();
            if ($rerollThreshold >= $diceType) {
              $detailText = $INVALID_ROLL_ERROR;
              break;  //Future note: This should break out of the big foreach ($rollTokens) loop
            }
            for ($k = 0; $k < $numberOfDice; $k++) {
              array_push ($rollResults, rand($rerollThreshold+1, $diceType));
            }
            if ($keepHighCount > 0 || $keepLowCount > 0) {
               if ($keepHighCount > 0) {
                  $keepCount = $keepHighCount;
                  $selectorFunction = "max";
               } else {
                  $keepCount = $keepLowCount;
                  $selectorFunction = "min";
               }
               if ($keepCount > $numberOfDice) {
                  $detailText = $INVALID_ROLL_ERROR;
                  break;  //Future note: This should break out of the big foreach ($rollTokens) loop
               }
               $keep = array();
               $discard = array();
               foreach ($rollResults as $key => $val) {
                 $discard[$key] = $val;
               }
               for ($k = 0; $k < $keepCount; $k++) {
                  $highest = call_user_func($selectorFunction, $discard);
                  $highestIndex = array_search($highest, $discard);
                  array_push($keep, $highest);
                  unset($discard[$highestIndex]);
               }
               foreach ($rollResults as $roll) {
                  $keepIndex = array_search($roll, $keep);
                  $discardIndex = array_search($roll, $discard);
                  if ($keepIndex !== False) {
                     $detailText .= "$roll ";
                     $subTotal += $roll;
                     unset($keep[$keepIndex]);
                  } else {
                     $detailText .= "<strike>$roll</strike> ";
                     unset($discard[$discardIndex]);
                  }
               }
            } else {
               foreach ($rollResults as $rollResult) {
                  $detailText .= "$rollResult ";
                  $subTotal += $rollResult;
               }
            }
            $subTotal *= $rollSign;
            $detailText .= " (Total = $subTotal)";
            $rollTotal += $subTotal;
         }
      }
   } else {
      $detailText = $INVALID_ROLL_ERROR;
      $rollTotal = "0";
   }
   $detailText .= "<br><strong>Total</strong>: " . $rollTotal;
   $detailText = "<strong>Dice Roll:</strong> " . $inputClean . "<br>$detailText";
   return array('input'=>$inputText, 'total'=>$rollTotal, 'detailText'=>$detailText);
}
?>
```

Comment: Is this dice roller string format your invention or are you adopting someone else's format?  Are you "in control of the expected format" for the input?  In other words, do you have the authority to refine the format?  Specifically, if a portion of a given string is "non-random arithmetic" (`+5`), can you define that the THAT substring must be the final part of the expression (instead of being the first substring or positioned somewhere in the middle)?  The reason I ask is because that would simplify the parsing algorithm.

Comment: Good question. I am in control of the expected format, but I want the format to be user friendly. This is for a role-playing game forum (Dungeons and Dragons) so it wouldn't be uncommon for a person to want to break down their roll for ease of reading / confirmation. For example, 1d20 + 5 + 2 + 1.

Comment: I'm not a D&D fellow.  What is the relevance of multiple non-randomised substrings?  `+5+2+1`? Does `+8` somehow not capture an integral aspect of the roll expression?

Comment: Yea. There's definitely value in being able to break out constants.  If your attack is "1d20+13" the other players can't really figure out where that 13 came from, or confirm that it's right. If it's "1d20+6+4+2+1" they will have a much better understanding of things without having to ask.

Comment: So then, is it also valuable to write the constants at the start and/or in the middle of the sequence -- because it paints a clearer picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Regarding the overall format of the string, I recommend requiring that non-roll-based substrings be postioned after roll-based substrings.  This will vastly improve the readability, elegance, and efficiency of the string/code. This requirement will ensure that input strings never start with a sign and that all non-roll-based substrings will be signed. More specifically, instead of using regex to validate, chunk, then make successive matches in a loop; you should be able to use a single pattern with `\G` in `preg_match_all()` to completely parse the string, then handle the capture groups based on their index.
- I don't think I support the allowance of multiple non-random roll tokens in a single sequence (`3d6-5+3`) -- this should be discouraged/disallowed purely because it looks messy.
- I am also not sure why you can't have min/max selections (`v` and `^`) on separate "roll tokens". I think this example should be valid/acceptable:

  ```
  5d8v2+2d20v1
  ```

  Roll an eight-sided die five times keeping the lowest two rolls, added to, roll a twenty-sided die twice keeping the lower roll.
- You can eliminate this condition:

  ```
  if (empty($rollToken)) {
      continue;
  }
  ```

  if you deny the empty elements in the `preg_split()` call like this:

  ```
  preg_split('/(?=[+-])/', $inputClean, null, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY)
  ```
- If a roll token is found to not require a randomizing step, just add the value to the subtotal after casting as `(int)`. There is no need to separate the sign from the integer in this case.

If you agree to tightening the string format, I think I'd be interested in offering a complete regex pattern for you.

---

UPDATE: I love the idea of inventing a purposeful notation (I once had a go at a pinochle notation many years ago). I used a couple days of commute time on my phone to try to rewrite your script, so here it is...

Here is the only regex pattern that I needed to parse/validate/chunk your input strings:

```
~
\G(^-?|[+-])
(?:
  (\d+d\d+)(r\d+)?([v^]\d+)?
  |
  (\d+)
)
(?=[+-]|$)
~x
```

This pattern will check from start to finish for consecutive, valid sequences (random or constant).  For the specific breakdown, please refer to regex101.com

Once `preg_match_all()` has broken the string into meaningful groups, no more regex is required.

I also streamlined the high/low roll keeping technique.

If something isn't fit for purpose, let me know and I'll try to fix it.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kI5eo))

```
function parseRollCode($rollCode) {
    $cleanRollCode = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', strtolower($rollCode));
    $intro = "<strong>Dice Roll:</strong> {$cleanRollCode}";
    $error = "Invalid Roll Code";
    $result = [
        'input'      => $rollCode,
        'total'      => 0,
        'detailText' => $intro
    ];

    if (!preg_match_all('~\G(^-?|[+-])(?:(\d+d\d+)(r\d+)?([v^]\d+)?|(\d+))(?=[+-]|$)~', $cleanRollCode, $out)) {
        $result['detailText'] .= "\n{$error}";
        return $result;
    }

    /*
    $out...
    [0] => roll tokens (optional leading sign)
    [1] => optional signs
    [2] => number&type die segments
    [3] => reroll threshold segments
    [4] => keep setting segments
    [5] => constant segments
    */

    foreach ($out[0] as $index => $segment) {
        $result['detailText'] .= "\n<strong>{$segment} Results:</strong>";
        if (!empty($out[5][$index])) {
            $result['detailText'] .= ' (subtotal: ' . ((int)$segment) . ')';
            $result['total'] += $segment;
        } else {
            // dice count & die type
            [$diceCount, $dieType] = explode('d', $out[2][$index], 2);

            // positive or negative arithmetic
            $signFactor = (!empty($out[1][$index][0]) && $out[1][$index][0] == '-' ? -1 : 1);

            // reroll threshold
            $rerollThreshold = (int)ltrim($out[3][$index] ?? 0, 'r');
            if ($rerollThreshold >= $dieType) {
                return ['input' => $rollCode, 'total' => 0, 'detailText' => "{$intro}\n{$error}"];
            }
            $rollResults = [];
            for ($r = 0; $r < $diceCount; ++$r) {
                $rollResults[] = rand($rerollThreshold + 1, $dieType);
            }

            // keep settings
            if (!empty($out[4][$index])) {
                $keepCount = ltrim($out[4][$index], '^v');
                if ($keepCount > $diceCount) {
                    return ['input' => $rollCode, 'total' => 0, 'detailText' => "{$intro}\n{$error}"];
                }
                if ($out[4][$index][0] == '^') {
                    arsort($rollResults);
                } else {
                    asort($rollResults);
                }
                $keep = array_slice($rollResults, 0, $keepCount, true);
                $subtotal = array_sum($keep) * $signFactor;
                for ($i = 0, $len = count($rollResults); $i < $len; ++$i) {
                    $result['detailText'] .= ' ' .  ($keep[$i] ?? "<s>{$rollResults[$i]}</s>");
                }
                $result['detailText'] .= " (subtotal: {$subtotal})";
                $result['total'] += $subtotal;
            } else {
                $subtotal = array_sum($rollResults) * $signFactor;
                $result['detailText'] .= " " . implode(" ", $rollResults) . " (subtotal: {$subtotal})";
                $result['total'] += $subtotal;
            }
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$rolls = ["1 d2 0", "-1d20+5", "d20", "2d20^1", "4d6r1^3", "5d20^3", "5d8v2", "2d20v1", "5+3d4", "3d20^1",
   "3d6r1 + 1d4r2", "-1d20", "1d20+5", "1d20 + 5", "1d-20", "1d20+1d6", "5d20-3d6", "1d6r2", "5d6r-6", "3d20^1v1",
   "1d20r30", "1d20r20", "1d20r19", "1d20v2", "1d20v1", "1d20^2", "1d20+5d8r2^3-5-1d6+3d4+2-4+6-8"];
foreach ($rolls as $roll) {
    $rollResult = parseRollCode($roll);
    echo "{$rollResult['detailText']}\n<strong>Total:</strong> {$rollResult['total']}\n---\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to say a few words about the code:

- There is some duplicate functionality using the regular expressions to validate and split the string. IMO you should either

  - drop the `preg_split` and instead modify the "main" regular expression so that you can use the `matches` array that it returns, or
  - first execute the split and then verify each sub-string separately.
- You could also use either again the `matches` array from the main regex or `$rrx` (which by the way is a bad variable name, if you need a comment to explain it)  to parse the roll tokens instead of using three new regular expressions.
- The returned data could also be optimized:

  - It's a bit pointless to return `$inputText` since it's identical to what the caller passed in. I'd either drop it, or at least return `$inputClean`, or even return a "normalized" string (for example, `1d6-1`, `+1d6-1` and `-1+1d6` could all return `1d6-1`), but that would require some additional work.
  - Also the function shouldn't return a hard coded (error) texts and HTML. Instead it should return an error code (`array('error' => $errorCode)`) and the data about the roll in a structured format that then can transformed into HTML (or an alternative format, for example BBCode) in a separate function/template.
- Generally the code could do with splitting up into more functions.

Finally: I'm not a big fan of using `v`/`^` if this syntax is supposed to be user friendly for two reasons:

- It may not be obvious to all users that `v` is supposed to symbolize an arrow and they may wonder what the letter "v" stands for.
- The character `^` isn't commonly used by an average user and maybe difficult to type on some (non-US) keyboard layouts where it's a [dead key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key).

Comment: I 100% agree re the naming of $rrx, but I didn't want the regex line to get too long. Any suggestions?

Comment: What syntax would you recommend as an alternative to ^ and v?

Comment: Re `$rrx`: Name it `$singleRollRegex` and put the large regex into a variable in a separate line.

Comment: Re `v`/`^`: If you only want one character, then `<`/`>` would be OK, but in the long term, if you are considering adding more features, you may generally want to find a more expressive/less cryptic syntax.

Comment: NB: The wikipedia article on [dice notations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_notation) mentions other possible notations: e.g. `4d6k3` where `k3` means "keep three highest dice"; or `4d6-L` where `-L` means "subtract lowest die", etc.